# How to determine the `/dev` path to a Flash drive

Tags: usb-drive

When does a Flash drive inserted end up being `/dev/sdb` as opposed to `/dev/sdb1` or vice versa? What is the command line that will determine the path of a newly inserted Flash drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/sdb` refers to the drive itself—the entire flash drive, not a partition on it.  This is useful if you are going to do something affecting the entire flash drive, such as reformatting it, but not so useful if your flash drive is already formatted and you just want to access files stored on it.  (Note: by "reformatting the entire drive", I really meant "changing the type of partition map", since reformatting a single partition wouldn't involve `/dev/sdb`.)

`/dev/sdb1` refers to the first partition on the `/dev/sdb` drive.  If the flash drive has at least one partition (i.e. it has been formatted for use), you should have both `/dev/sdb` *and* `/dev/sdb1` after inserting the flash drive.  You may also have `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb3`, etc., if your flash drive has more partitions, but if you are simply using a flash drive out of the box and haven't done any special formatting to it, you will likely have only one partition filling the entire flash drive.  (For the sake of completeness, the partition will need a *filesystem* on it to store files, but again, a flash drive fresh out of the box will have this already set up.)

It's important to know that the letter `b` in that name should not be relied on.  Depending on numerous factors (such as whether other USB drives have been used, in what sequence the drives are discovered by your computer, and many other factors), your computer may create a device node for your flash drive at `/dev/sdc` instead of `/dev/sdb`, or even at `/dev/sdd`.  (The partition will have a matching name with a trailing `1` in any case: `/dev/sdc1` or `/dev/sdd1`, as applicable.)

This brings us to the next part of your question: How to determine what "name" the computer has assigned to your flash drive.  By now you understand that it's not `/dev/sdb` *as opposed to* `/dev/sdb1`; instead, it's *both* `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1`, as opposed to *both* of `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdc1`.  The easiest way to list this information is with the `lsblk` command.  That will list the block devices connected to your computer.  It should be fairly obvious which is the flash drive, but to be certain, you can run `lsblk` before inserting the flash drive, and then run it again immediately after inserting the flash drive.  This way, the device that is showing up newly in the command output is the flash drive.

And lastly, if you happen to be asking this question to help automate the mounting of a flash drive, I recommend learning about the `/etc/fstab` file, and about using "device labels" or "device UUIDs" to specify which drive to mount.

Comment: And of course, if you are a Linux guru already, no offense intended!  ;)  Just noticed your reputation score....

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, thanks.

Comment: Great!  :)  If it answered your question, could you take a moment to click the checkmark to the left of the answer?  "Accepting" the answer like this is the best way to express thanks on this site.

Comment: Nice answer. I want to argue with one point though. 'Formatting' a partition aka. putting a filesystem on it, uses the partition identifiers `/dev/sdb1..n`. The creation of the partition table happens on the bare block device `/dev/sdb`. In principle one creates a partition table on `sdb` with e.g `fdisk` which makes `sdb1..sdbn` available. On those partitions you may then create whatever filesystems you like.

Comment: @nephente: Good point, I edited to clarify what I meant.